# How to use string variable without unwrap optional value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am very confused with unwrap fundamentals of Swift 2.0. I have bellow code to display last name string value from dictionary to label.

```
let lastName:String? = self.userDict.objectForKey("last_name")
self.lblLastName.text = "Last Name: " + lastName!
```

but some times this code run before value assign in to `self.userDict` at that time above code get `self.userDict.objectForKey("last_name")` nil and throw an error.

For solution i modified my code like bellow and keep that value unwrap but compiler don't take it as valid

```
let lastName:String? = self.userDict.objectForKey("last_name")
self.lblLastName.text = "Last Name: " + lastName?   //--ERROR: Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

Please suggest me valid way to fulfil the requirement.

Comment: You should use ! instead of ? to force unwrap optional

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: @ozzyzig No. That's a very bad advice. Force unwrapping leads to crashes on user side. Instead, always use safe techniques like optional binding, optional chaining, etc.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say test with an if let statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide a way to handle cases when dictionary has no value for key `"last_name"` and returns `nil`.  Easiest way is to use [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60) `??`:

> The nil coalescing operator (`a ?? b`) unwraps an optional `a` if it contains a value, or returns a default value `b` if `a` is `nil`. The expression `a` is always of an optional type. The expression `b` must match the type that is stored inside `a`.

You could do something like:

```
let lastName: String = self.userDict.objectForKey("last_name") ?? "N/A"
self.lblLastName.text = "Last Name: " + lastName
```

Comment: Solved +1 :) thanks for help. But please can you give little exploitation on `??` operator. I am totally unaware of this.

Comment: Yes, I was busy with exactly that.  Please see the edits to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use ***Optional Binding*** to check if the retrieved value from dictionary is nil or not. Then you can assign the string to your label (`lblLastName`) conditionally.

```
if let lastName = self.userDict.objectForKey("last_name") {
    self.lblLastName.text = "Last Name: " + lastName
} else {
    self.lblLastName.text = "Last Name: " + "some other hard coded string"
}
```